# Using static methods in Android?

Tags: android, static, static-methods

I already made some Apps in Android and noticed that I am often using static methods.

For example I have an Class which extends `PreferenceFragment`. In this PreferenceFragment I set an `onClick` event on a `Button`.

```
    Button btn = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    btn.setText("Save");
    v.addView(btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SettingsActivity.finishActivityWithResultOkey();            
        }
    });
```

Then I'm calling a static method in my `SettingsActivity` which finishes this `Activity`. Is this a good way of doing what I want to do? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: it is not a good way, because the method to finish an activity is an instance method. In your case, you can simply call `getActivity.finish()` to finish the activity

Comment: i think you missunderstood me. The code i have Posted above is a class with the name PrefFragment and i am calling a static method of another Acivity called SettingsActivity to finish this SettingsAcivity.

Comment: you are trying to finish another activity? one that is not displayed? not a good idea. for all you know, that activity could have been destroyed by the system already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Android (in memory managed programming languages like Java, more precisely), `static` methods can lead to "memory leaks" if not used correctly. I've quoted "memory leaks" as they are not the pure definition of memory leaks, like in C++ where you forget to remove some items from memory and lose the reference to them (and thus cannot clear them later on - at least not easily), but more like keeping on to references when you no longer need them and preventing the GC from doing its job in clearing that memory for you. There are a lot of articles on the web that cover this (search for "Android static memory leak") and a lot of other questions on SO that have been asked about this (see [[static][Android][memory-leaks] tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/static+android+memory-leaks)), so I won't go into this.

For your particular case, in order to avoid possible memory leaks, you can get the `Activity` from the `Fragment` object that your anonymous `OnClickListener` object is tied to by using `MyFragmentClass.this.getActivity()`, cast it to, say, `SettingsActivity` (as is the case here) and call `.finishActivityWithResultOkey()` on it. It's best that you guard your cast too.

Here's an example of how the code could look like:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Activity activity = MyFragmentClass.this.getActivity();
            if(activity instanceof SettingsActivity)
               ((SettingsActivity)activity).finishActivityWithResultOkey();
            else
               throw new IllegalStateException("This OnClickListener requires a SettingsActivity to start the fragment containig it"); //helps with debugging
        }
    });
```

As a note: `MyFragmentClass` refers to the class of the fragment that you're putting this code in :)

Comment: i justed tried your code and it is working ! But i can't understand why! How can activity be an instanceof SettingsAcivity ?

Comment: Well, isn't `SettingsActivity` the activity you used to create your fragment? `Fragment.getActivity()` returns the activity used to create it

Comment: Ah yes now i understand thanks ! But let me show you another example where i am using a static method and where your solution won't work. In my finishActivityWithResultOkey() method i want to call another static method in my AppWidgetProvider which create an Database with the defaultSharedPreferences and starts an Alarm via Alarmmanager. How should i do this without an static method in my AppWidgetProvider ? Thank you...

Comment: As I said, the solution covers this **particular case**. It is not an all-rounds solution and I doubt there is such an all-round solution. There are cases where you just can't avoid `static`. My answer relies on the `Fragment.getActivity()` method and won't work without it :). Also, the comment above could be suitable for a different question and it is hard to answer it in comments without more detailed information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Java property known as mirroring. 
Below I use the property to finish the activity.

```
 Button btn = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    btn.setText("Save");
    v.addView(btn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SettingsFragment.this.getActivity().finish();            
        }
    });
```

Comment: `SettingsActivity.this.finish()` refers to the enclosing `Activity` which might not be present (unless this code is put in that `Activity`). Also, if the code was in that `Activity` the `finishActivityWithResultOkey` would be available in the anonymous class used as the listener. The asker stated that he has the code in a `Fragment`, so in order for that to work he might have to get the `Activity` from that `Fragment` like: `MyFragmentClass.getActivity().finish()`

Comment: what are you talking about

Comment: I've removed the downvote as per your edit (changed it to an upvote actually as this is a valid answer now). Before the edit you were using `SettingsActivity` instead of `SettingsFragment` in your answer (revised here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26534852/revisions)