# How to avoid using static methods

Tags: android, static, static-methods

As this question ([Using static methods in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534660/using-static-methods-in-android)) is already answered, i have another case where i am not sure if using a static method is valid or not.

In an Acitivty called SettingsActivity i have an method called finishActivityWithResultOkey():

```
public void finishActivityWithResultOkey() {
    Intent resultValue = new Intent();
    resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId); 

    MyWidgetProvider.setSharedPreferences();
    MyWidgetProvider.startScreenReciever();
    MyWidgetProvider.startClockTickAlarm(false);


    context.setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
    context.finish();       
}
```

Before i finish my SettingsActivity i am calling those 3 STATIC Methods in another Class which extends AppWidgetProvider:

```
    public void setSharedPreferences() {
        db = new SharedPreferencesDatabase(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(_context));        
    }

    public static void startScreenReciever() {
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
        screenReciever = new ScreenReceiver();
        _context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(screenReciever, filter);  
    }

    public static void startClockTickAlarm(boolean code) {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)_context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
            long duration;
            if(code)
                duration = utcMillisNextMin();
            else
                duration = utcMillisNextSec();
            if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, duration, createClockTickIntent());
            } else {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC,  duration, createClockTickIntent());
            }                                       
    }
```

I am wondering if those static methods are really needed or is there another better way of doing this without using static methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppWidgetProvider extends BroadcastReceiver so you can simply send an intent to perform the action you need.

Widget:

```
FinishActivity() {
    setSharedPreferences();
    startScreenReciever();
    startClockTickAlarm(false);
}
```

Add an onRecieve to the widget to read the intent and call FinishActivity().  The activity will be the one creating and sending the Intent.  Might look something like this:

```
Intent uiIntent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_WIDGET_FINISH_FROM_ACTIVITY);
context.sendBroadcast(uiIntent);
```

Comment: perfect, with this simple solution i was able to eliminate all static methods !

Comment: Happy to help.  For non widgets you can also just write a broadcast receiver and store it as a data member of your class if you want to call a method on that class through an intent.